# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': The specified module could not be found

Tags: ocr, tesseract, tess4j

This is kind of duplicate question, But none of the answers helped to resolve this. I did this,

1. Pulled code from here
2. Added -Djna.library.path=${workspace_loc:/ocr-tess4j-example}/dlls/x64 in VM arguments, This folder has three dll files gsdll64.dll,liblept168.dll and libtesseract302.dll
3. Executed the java file "TesseractExample.java"

Getting below exception.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': The specified module could not be found.`

I have tried below options but nothing works

1. Setting jna.library.path in VM variable
2. Setting it in System.setProperty
3. Kept those dll files in root folder and without setting jna.library.path

Please help me to resolve this

Comment: You have Visual C++ Redistributable for VS2012 installed?

Comment: Oops Thanks man !!!. This is the only step missed in all the forums. May be earlier versions have VC++, But Im using Windows 10 which doesn't have VC++. Its working after I've installed.